# How to create a map with an attribute as a key and a maximum value as a value

Tags: java, function, stream, collectors

So, In college we are working with csv files and streams. Right now I am doing some homework but I've been stuck in this exercise for some days now. I have a csv file with some data about accidents (like the accident severity, the number of victims and so) and I have a function that reads that data and converts it to a list of Accident objects (which has a property for each type of data the csv has):

```java
private Severity severity;
private Integer victims;

public Accident(Severity severity, Integer victims) {
this.severity = severity;
this.victims = victims;
}
```

I have saved that list in an object and I can call the list with `getAccidents()`:

```java
private List<Accident> accidents;

public AccidentArchive(List<Accident> accidents) {
this.accidents = accidents;

public Map<Severity, Integer> getMaxVictimsPerSeverity() {  //Not working correctly
return getAccidents().stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Accident::getSeverity, Accident::getVictims, Integer::max));
```

Right now, I have to make a function that does what the title says. I have thought that the map keys could be the severity (which is an enumerate with values slight, serious and fatal) and the values could be the highest number of victims of every accident with that same severity. For example, the map output could be: `SLIGHT=1, SERIOUS=3, FATAL=5`.

I have tried using the Collections, Collectors and Comparator libraries but I can't find any way to divide all the Accidents in each severity value, get the maximum number of victims for each and then save both values in a `Map<Severity, Integer>` map.
The function right now starts this way:
`public Map<Severity, Integer> getMaxVictimsPerSeverity() { return getAccidents().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Accident::getSeverity, ...))` and then I have tried a lot of things but I can't find any way to make it return what I want. I am still a newby and I don't understand a lot of things yet so ask if I have forgotten anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a value extractor to get the victims of each accident, and a reducer to keep the highest number of victims.

```
return getAccidents().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Accident::getSeverity, Accident::getVictims, Integer::max));
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work well. I have been playing with some example objects changing the severity and victims value and the output seems to have the same format I want but not the correct values. For example, the output could be `SLIGHT=1, SERIOUS=2, FATAL=5` but there are Accident objects with SLIGHT severity and a victims value greater than 1 and so. I have been trying to find some patron in the output by changing the values but I am unable to find why it is wrong

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a minimal implementation of Accident.

Comment: Okay It actually works well. I just got confused because I didn't remember that I had removed some accidents from the list while trying other functions. Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to group by Severity and count the number of Accidents in each group.

```
Map<Severity, Long> counted = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Accident::getSeverity, Collectors.counting()));
```

This should help you achieve what you are looking for.

Here is a working example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Accident a1 = new Accident(Severity.SLIGHT);
      Accident a2 = new Accident(Severity.SERIOUS);
      Accident a3 = new Accident(Severity.SLIGHT);
      Accident a4 = new Accident(Severity.FATAL);
      Accident a5 = new Accident(Severity.FATAL);
      
      List<Accident> list= new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(a1);
      list.add(a2);
      list.add(a3);
      list.add(a4);
      list.add(a5);
      
      Map<Severity, Long> counted = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Accident::getSeverity, Collectors.counting()));

      System.out.println(counted);
    }
    
    static class Accident{
        Severity severtity;
        Accident(Severity s){
            this.severtity = s;
        }

        public Severity getSeverity(){
            return severtity;
        }
    }

    static enum Severity{
        SLIGHT, SERIOUS, FATAL;
    }
}
```

The Result: `{FATAL=2, SLIGHT=2, SERIOUS=1}`

Comment: OP doesn't want the *count* of each severity; OP wants the greatest number of victims of any accident in each severity.

Comment: Yeah... I'm sorry I explained myself badly. I was meaning that the value of the map should be the highest 
number of victims value that any Accident object have with the same severity value.